# Matlab: Help Solving a 2nd order ODE with the derivative input being a function of time

Tags: matlab

I have been going round and round in circles trying to get Matlab to solve the resonator circuit equation with a time varying input voltage. It works just fine as long as all the in arguments of the derivative functions are scalar values.

I have gone through others questions and found answers suggesting anonymous functions or using interpolation. When I try to implement these suggestions, I get a return error that tells me I do not have enough initial conditions to match the output of ode function or the matrices being concatenated do not match..

Here is my code:

```
%% Define Parameters

f0=1494.72e6;
Q=80;
R=1;
L=(Q*R)/(2*pi*f0);
C=1/((2*pi*f0)^2*L);
tp=71e-9;
N=2^16;
n=(0:N-1);
TT=1e-6;
h=TT/N;
t=n*h;
start_pulse=1;
end_pulse=round(tp/h);
V=zeros(size(t));

%% Create Voltage Pulse
for ii=1:length(n);
    if ii>=start_pulse && ii<=end_pulse
        V(ii)=sin(2*pi*f0*t(ii));
    end
end

%% 

tspan=[0 TT];
x0=[0 0];
sol=ode45(@ode,tspan,x0,[],V);
int=(0:h:TT);
sint=deval(sol,int);
plot(int,sint*C);
```

MY ode funtion is the following:

```
function [ dx ] = ode( t,x,V)
f0=1494.72e6;
Q=80;
R=1;
L=(Q*R)/(2*pi*f0);
C=1/((2*pi*f0)^2*L);
dx1 = x(2);
dx2 =((-x(1)./(L*C))-(R*x(2)./L)-(V./(L*C)));
dx = [dx1; dx2];
end
```

As you can see, L,C,and R all are scalar values. If I replace 'V' in dx2 with '1', the program runs just fine. I need to change V to be the matrix defined above.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks in advance!!! :)